# Get unique list of all template variables from template (html) file using regex or bash command

Tags: regex, bash, templates

I have html templates and I want to get list of all template variables like :

```
<li>User ID <!--{ID}--></li>
```

`<!--{ID}-->` is a template variables

## Edit:

Regex pattern for doing this is :

```
\<\!--\{(.*?)\}--\>
```

I need to catch only unique occurrences for any variable e.g `<!--{ID}-->` might be present multiple time in template

Comment: Did you try piping your output to `sort -u`?

Comment: @Jaypal I have not tried anything using bash.Regex (using php) is working fine but now I need to find Unique instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -lne '{ while (/<!--{(.*?)}-->/g) {$t{$1}++}  } 
        END{ print for keys %t }' input.html
```

With less Perl statements:

```
perl -lpe '{s/.*?(<!--{[^}]*}-->)/\1\n/g}' input | \
        grep '<!--{' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Would you like to suggest regex alternative ?. Thanks for the bash command that is perfect.

Comment: are there multiple template parameters on a line?

Comment: Then it is not possible with sed and with simple regexes, I would go with the perl one-liner.

Comment: your first command is perfectly returning unique list of variables , but I also need a regex version to use within php e.g using preg_match_all().However, I ll accept the answer w.r.t your first command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ack -o '\<\!--\{(.*?)\}--\>' input.html | uniq -c
```

Comment: @sakhunzai I would have suggested `grep -oP` but `grep` on mac doesn't support `perl` based regexes.